# n dimensional measure of homeomorphism of interval

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow I \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ (where $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $n>1$) be homeomorphism. Can the n-dimensional lebesgue measure of $I$ be positive?

Comment: Possibly related: [Osgood curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. What you're after is called an Osgood curve.

Here is a fractal example in dimension $2$, from Wikipedia. You start from a triangle (which could have dimension $n$ harmlessly) and at each step you remove a smaller triangle with thinner and thinner width.

[image]